# Is pylons project alive?

Tags: python

I am wondering what is status of pylons. I currently know sth about django and trying to learn sth new and found pylons  might be a good next step but it is still active? I mean it don't have sense to learn sth which is not currently active and supported for begginers so here is my question.
Best regards

Comment: Why abbreviate "something" to "sth" when there is no other txt-speak in the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's very much alive, and recent developments are highly exciting:

http://docs.pylonsproject.org/en/latest/docs/pyramid.html